# Cannot SSH from OS X Mavericks to Solaris server

Tags: macos, terminal, ssh

Well, this is embarrassing. It was a case sensitive issue. Prior to posting the -v output on this site, and probably due to looking at this problem for too long, I forgot the fundamental rule of case sensitivity !! Was trying to log into the Solaris server using an all lower-case user name. The user id on the Mac has an u/c alpha first character (remainder is l/c). Tried it and it worked.
Just need to find a hole deep enough now but thank you to all who tried to assist.

Comment: In debugging ssh issues, it often helps to look over the verbose output `ssh -vv` and add more or less `v` to increase/decrease the amount of debug. The problem could be on either end but it's probably an easy remedy once we get the underlying failure point in the negotiation.

Comment: Yes, post the -vvv (all 3 v's please!) output.  We'll be able to see which host is having problems opening the key file, and possibly be able to provide specific help.  You should be sure to change the hostnames/IPs so that you're not inviting naughty people to try mean things (e.g. use sun.example.com and mac.example.com, and use ip addresses that begin with 10.)

Answer (score 1):

Try and ssh into the solaris machine with the following options

```
ssh bob@solaris -vvv -F /dev/null -o PreferredAuthentications=Password
```

There are a couple of things to look at:

- Does your mac have an ssh config file? If so, bypass it with `-F /dev/null`
- Do you have multiple ssh keys? If so, select the correct one with -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa
- What protocol are you using? Check the sshd_config file on the server to see if you are using protocol 1 or 2.
- Have you installed / restarted the ssh-server daemon on the server?

Tail the logs on the server to see what errors it prints. Not sure about solaris, but on CentOS the logs are in `/var/log/auth/audit.log`